# Does Sophia key-value storage support multi-process access?

Tags: tarantool

I can not find any mention of this feature on the official site of [Sophia](http://sophia.systems/)

Comment: Did you mean Tarantool with sophia engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Sophia only supports multi-thread access. More information can be found in Sophia Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sophia-database

Also, sophia-only related questions can be asked using #sophia tag.
Thanks